# How to load view file from another root directory in Laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, view

I want to load view file from another root directory.

Example :
public function getProducts(Request $request)
{
return view(`http://localhost/laravelApp/view/products`, $data);
}
`http://localhost/laravel/view` this is my another view file directory and 'products' is view file name and my laravel project directory is laravelApp. My laravel version 5.8

Comment: This is not possible to load from another project directory, Move the file into same project or you can use file_get_contents to get the content of file

Answer (score 0):

you can use `{{url('../other-project-name/view/my-view')}}`
or `return view(url('../other-project-name/view/my-view'));` in your case

Edit: This might help you to debug sometimes : https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections#method-dd